# True, False, Yes and No button does not get selected

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of letter buttons from A-Z and I also have 4 other buttons ("True","False","Yes" and "No")

The html code which displays the 4 buttons ("True","False","Yes" and "No") is below:

```
<td>
    <input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerTrueName"  id="answerTrue"  type="button"   value="True"    onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
    <input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerFalseName" id="answerFalse"     type="button"   value="False"   onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
    <input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerYesName"   id="answerYes"   type="button"   value="Yes"     onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
    <input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerNoName"    id="answerNo"        type="button"   value="No"      onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
    </td>
```

The code below controls an "Add row" button where when clicked it will turn off all the buttons and it should turn on only the required buttons depending on the button's id matching the answer.

```
    function addwindow(btn) { 
        var answers = $.map(btn.split(''),function(chr){   return "#answer"+chr;  }).join(', ');
$('.answerBtns').removeClass('answerBtnsOff').removeClass('answerBtnsOn');
        $('.answerBtns').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
        $(answers).addClass("answerBtnsOn");
    }
```

The problem is that I click on the "Add row" button and the Answer was "True", then it should turn off all buttons and only turn on the "True" button (#answerTrue). But it is not turning on this button for this example. In fact it doesn't turn on those 4 buttons ("True","False","Yes","No"). Does anyone know why these 4 buttons won't turn on after "Add row" button is clicked?

UPDATE:

The url to the application is [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text16.php). Please follow steps below to be able to use the app:

- Step 1: When you open applicaton, you see a green plus button on the
  page, click on it and it will display a modal window.
- Step 2: In modal window there is a search bar, type in "AAA" and
  submit search, you will see a bunch of rows appear.
- Step 3: In the first row, you see under "Answer" colum that the
  answer is B, click on the "Add" button within this row, the modal
  window will close and you will see that the answer buttons have been
  displayed with the "B" button highlighted.

Now this works fine but it only works for letter buttons:

- Step 4: Click on the green plus button again and this time perform
  the search for "true";
- Step 5: This time you will see one row appear when under the "Answr"
  column the answer is "True". Add this row by clicking on the "Add"
  button
- Step 6: You will see that it displays the "True" and "False" buttons
  but the "True" button is not highlighted, even though the answer is
  "True".

Why doesn't it highlight this button?

Comment: You did a very good job explaining your situation.  Can you please trim down your post to contain only the problematic areas?  Right now its hard to see the problem because you get lost in the explanation.

Comment: Much much better!  Thanks... I'm not sure if i get what you are trying to do here yet... You want to click on one of these buttons and disable the other 3?

Comment: @Lix No what's up is that I have an "Answer" column which contains a lot of rows. Lets say one row under the "Answer" column contains the answer "True" and I add this row, all the current buttons should turn off and the "True" answer button should turn on by locating it's id `"#answerTrue"`. At the moment all the buttons turn off but the "True" button in this example doesn't turn on.

Comment: @Lix can I provide you a url to the app with some steps to follow so you can see what is happening for yourself so you can understand it a lot better?

Comment: Give us 10 mins, while I write up steps :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not going to be here much longer. I'll come take a look when I return.

Comment: @Lix I have included url to app and steps to follow in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suggestion, Instead than:

```
$('.answerBtns').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
$(answers).addClass("answerBtnsOn");
```

try:

```
$(answers).addClass("answerBtnsOn").siblings().addClass('answerBtnsOff');
```

But the problem here is that `answer` does not contain the correct button, instead you are selecting `#answerT`.

your problem is here:

```
var answers = $.map(btn.split(''),function(chr){   return "#answer"+chr;  }).join(', ');
```

Try to do some debugging, alerts, and probably by adding some `if`.  Try this code

```
if(btn=="True" || btn=="False" || btn=="Yes" || btn=="No"){
    var answers = '#answer'+btn;
} else {
    var answers = $.map(btn.split(''),function(chr){   return "#answer"+chr;  }).join(', ');
}
```

Comment: I have included this code in the addwindow() function: `if(btn=="True"){
    alert("True");
} else if(btn=="False") {
    alert("False");
}` If the Answer is True when the user clicked on the "Add" button, it does display the alert message "True", so it recognise the answer through the alert, just need to be able to highlight the button

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you only are adding the answerBtnsOn-class, but not removing the answerBtnsOff-class.

Try adding:

```
$(answers).removeClass("answerBtnsOff");
```

Also, instead of map, I think you can just select them using the class:

```
$(".answerBtns").addClass("answerBtnsOn");
$(".answerBtns").removeClass("answerBtnsOff");
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the full code for this function, can you please look at the updated "addwindow()" function in my code because I think I have already covered what you are suggesting in your answer?

Comment: You are adding answerBtnsOff to all before you also add answerBtnsOn to the right ones. If you use an inspector to check what classes are set, what does it say?

Comment: I have included url to the application in my question, you can see and use the application to see what is happening and perform any checks you want. I have never used inspector before so be easier if you can perform any neccessary checks and other things you want to see :)

Comment: I'm sorry I could not be to any more help. I inspected some, but the code is very un-organized and "messy". So I did not find it.

Comment: Ok thats fine, I tried to quickly conjure up the demo so that people can use it. I will try and clean it up best I can now if you still want to help.

Comment: I have tried cleaning up the code and updated app, if you want another look then go ahead, hopefully this is better